# Are all real-valued continous functions in $\mathbb{R}^2$ on a compact space integrable?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

If you look at all continous functions on a compact intervall in $\mathbb{R}$ this statement is true. They are all integrable ([proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Function_is_Riemann_Integrable)).
Is this true in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and higher dimensional spaces?

I can't think of a function where this is false but I'm not quite sure.
I tried to apply Fubini's theorem to break it down to but therefore the functions needs to be integrable in the first place.

Is there an simple argument I missed?

Comment: It's not enough to know that they're continuous and bounded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continuous functions on a compact set are bounded, and compact sets have finite Lebesgue measure, thus all such functions are integrable.

Comment: +1. But perhaps, for the sake of completeness, it would be good to recall that compact sets in Euclidean space have finite measure.

Comment: Fair enough, will edit.